# if several blade file extend the same content, how does blade know which to choose?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Sorry for the newbie question, but I'm confused in how blade knows what content to yield...

Say I have one index.blade.html file with `<body> @yield('content') </body>` but I have several files that all have:

```
@extends('index')
@section('content')
content
@endsection
```

If I have this setup in 3 different files that extend the index file, how does blade know which to choose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright  lets suppose you have this in your controller

```
public function index(){
    return view('index'); // View name must be inside ' '
}
```

and this route

```
Route::get('/','HomeController@index');
```

When you visit your home `exemple.com` the controller will return

```
index.blade.php
```

and this view extends `master.blade.php`

therefore the **Content section** of the `index.blade.php` will be added to the `master.blade.php`

if you visit another route that return another View (exemple: `login.blade.php`),
the content of that login view will be the content in the final compiled view* .

Comment: I see, so you should add the file with blade's "section" you want in the controller, and that will automatically grab whichever php file it is extending!

Comment: My question now is, I had a menu on the main index page, cut that out and pasted it in a different blade file, for keeping some order in my pages, but it won't get yielded properly. Do I have to add this menu.blade.php file somewhere in the controller as well?

Comment: yes, the content will be the content of the view returned by the controller. you usualy extend something that will be used in other views like a nav bar, and for your second question , no you dont (it deppends on the code and what you mean by wont get yielded properly.

Comment: I found out I could only use 1 '@yield' and have to use '@include' for the others!

Comment: of course, consider yield as reserving a place for content, it can only be once for each section